# Convert xls file to xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, interop, xls

I am a newbie in c#, i have to convert an excel file to an xml with simple nodes. I have done it so far with interop. I have written parts of code to open an xls , close an xls, get value of a cell by Get_range method, and release the object.

But, now i have to output an xml file, i have to goto a particular cell and print a node and a value of a cell. It can be a simple plain text also which i can output or we can use the linq Xelement and Xattributes as well. I think when using get_range:

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B3", "B3").Value2
```

i need to print the same in excel.

I am not sure how to do this, please guide me. The resulting xml should look something like this:

```
<WpData>
<WpType>Design</WpType>
<ReviewType>half</ReviewType>
<References>[1] https:///SysService/SysService_AsrDet/trunk/_doc/20_Design


</References>
<Author>deh</Author>
<Reviewer>abc</Reviewer>
</WpData>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try getting a `DataTable` from the xls using the appropriate OLEDB provider (Jet/Ace) then use [`DataTable.WriteXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Comment: But i have already strated with interop i would like to continue with this only, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You searching for xml serialization. You should define class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class WpData
{
   public string WpType { get; set; }
   public string ReviewType { get; set; }
   public string References { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
   public string Reviewer { get; set; }
}
```

Note `Serializable` attribute on class.

Then you should fill your object from excel data and use `XmlSerializer`:

```
WpData xmlSerializibleObject = new WpData();

//....
//here you should fill it from excel based on your data

//And then you can just serialize it to string 
string xmlString;
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlSerializibleObject.GetType());

using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, xmlSerializibleObject);
    xmlString = textWriter.ToString();
}
```

`xmlString` will have xml that you need is you fill your object correct from excel.

Comment: Will it still work if my resulting xml is bigger than that?

Comment: @user5440565 what do you mean when you say bigger? If you need additional fields just add them to your class. There are no limitation on field number.

Comment: i mean, that if i have big xml file with say 100 nodes, then do i need to add these one by one like these:
public string Reviewer { get; set; }    ??

Comment: @user5440565 yeap, you need to add them one by one.

Comment: @user5440565 no problem. I can say that there are another ways to do it but this way is one of the most cleanest and you can fully controll outputed xml structure.